# Can't read the value of an state which has been defined in a function

Tags: javascript, react-native, jsx

I am trying to fetch some data from an API and store one of its arrays inside the state and access it inside `componentWillMount()`! But when I try to the mentioned states value, I got undefined.

Here is my code:

```
componentWillMount() {

        this._fetchData()

************************************
        alert(this.state.openSellOffers)
************************************
    }

    _fetchData = async () => {

        let openSellOffersRes = await fetchOpenSellOffers()
        for (let sellOffer of openSellOffersRes.orders) {
            let sellObj = {
                _id: sellOffer._id,
                currencyValue: sellOffer.currencyValue,
                unitPrice: sellOffer.unitPrice,
                totalPrice: sellOffer.totalPrice,
                type: 'sell'
            }

            this.setState({
                openSellOffers: [...this.state.openSellOffers, sellObj]
            })
        }
    }

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            IRRBalance: 0,
            BTCBalance: 0,
            openBuyOffers: [],
            openSellOffers: [],
            closedBuyOffers: [],
            closedSellOffers: []
        }
    }
```

As you can see I use `alert()` for showing the states value. That is the point which I get undefined instead of the exact value which API responses.

How can I solve it?

Appreciates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically setState() works asynchronously. So you need to wait for a few nanoseconds to get the value. You can do it in 2 ways.

**1. Use await**

```js
componentWillMount() {
  await this._fetchData()
  alert(this.state.openSellOffers)
}

_fetchData = async () => {
  let openSellOffersRes = await fetchOpenSellOffers()
  for (let sellOffer of openSellOffersRes.orders) {
    let sellObj = {
      _id: sellOffer._id,
      currencyValue: sellOffer.currencyValue,
      unitPrice: sellOffer.unitPrice,
      totalPrice: sellOffer.totalPrice,
      type: 'sell'
    }

    this.setState({
      openSellOffers: [...this.state.openSellOffers, sellObj]
    })
  }
  return true;
}
```

**2. Use SetTimeOut **

```js
componentWillMount() {
  this._fetchData()
  setTimeout(() => {
    alert(this.state.openSellOffers)
  }, 100)
}

_fetchData = async () => {
  let openSellOffersRes = await fetchOpenSellOffers()
  for (let sellOffer of openSellOffersRes.orders) {
    let sellObj = {
      _id: sellOffer._id,
      currencyValue: sellOffer.currencyValue,
      unitPrice: sellOffer.unitPrice,
      totalPrice: sellOffer.totalPrice,
      type: 'sell'
    }

    this.setState({
      openSellOffers: [...this.state.openSellOffers, sellObj]
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Please, be careful with awaits and wrap them in try/catch blocks.